# Is it possible to use the same folder for Dropbox and SkyDrive?

Tags: windows-8, dropbox, onedrive

Is it possible to set the same folders to SkyDrive and dropbox? I would like to sync them both at the same time. How to perform this action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to change the Dropbox directory under its advanced settings.  You could set it to the SkyDrive folder.  You can not change the SkyDrive folder in its settings.  Most likely due to its integration with your Windows account.

I dont see doing this will cause a problem.  Definitely backup your data and test this before committing any important data.

EDIT:  I just tried this, DropBox will create a DropBox folder in the SkyDrive folder.  If you can live with that, then this will work.  So just save everything in the dropbox folder (under skydrive) and everything will be synced between the two accounts.

Comment: Please be aware that all new files withing SkyDrive/Dropbox folder will be uploaded twice (by SkyDrive and by Dropbox)

Comment: @gentlesea the link is dead.

Comment: Does this answer still work with the renamed "OneDrive", or did it only apply to SkyDrive?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm not committing a crime by reactivating an ancient question, but was just looking for the same thing and found a solution that worked a little better for me personally.

1. Sync DropBox with PC
2. Open Command Propmt
3. Navigate to SkyDrive folder (mine is `T:\cloud\SkyDrive`)
4. Use the following command. It will create a folder in the SkyDrive folder that links to the folder in the DropBox folder. I tested it and SkyDrive syncs these linked folders like any other folder. Needless to say you should replace "{folder name}" with the relevant folder name.

> mklink /d "{folder name}" "C:\cloud\Dropbox\{folder name}"

Repeat step (4) for every folder in the DropBox folder.

[This](http://darrylmiles.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/syncing-between-dropbox-and-microsoft-skydrive/) is where I found my answer, but I wrote it out in case the link dies someday.

A couple of things I'm going to test now is

1. Try and do the same thing with DropBox - let DropBox folder contain the links in stead of SkyDrive
2. Try the same thing with Google Drive
3. Attempt to have all three of them share a single folder that does not actually belong to any of them - let `T:\cloud\SkyDrive`, `T:\cloud\DropBox` and `T:\cloud\GoogleDrive` contain only links to T:\cloud\Content - and have all three of them sync that way

I hope this help.

Regards,

me

**EDIT:** Having DropBox sync linked folder also works, so having DropBox and SkyDrive share a folder not actually belonging to one of them should work. Now I only need to test it with GoogleDrive.

**EDIT:** I tested this with Google Drive. It seems Google Drive doesn't sync symbolically linked folders like DropBox and SkyDrive does.

Comment: Google Drive doesn't let you map a drive name to that folder, so the way it presents Google Drive is different from the way OneDrive ane DropBox works.

Comment: Does this answer still apply to OneDrive?